# How do I use the split function in Google Sheets correctly?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to get data from the text found in 2.. In 1. Is the data I have available and in 3. You will find the wanted result.

1. I have the following information available

| Categories |
| --- |
| Kleur |
| Soorthek |
| Bevestigingswijze |

2. I am getting this text from scraping: `BevestigingswijzeKlembevestigingKleurWitSoorthekSpijlenhek`
3. I want this as a result by using a function in Google Sheets.

| Wanted Result |
| --- |
| KleurWit |
| SoorthekSpijlenhek |
| BevestigingswijzeKlembevestiging |

Thank you in advance!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this with an Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). To achieve this, follow these steps:

- In your spreadsheet, select **Tools > Script editor** to open a script bound to your file.
- Copy this function in the script editor, and save the project:

```
function splitScrape(categories, scrape) {
  const indexes = categories.map(c => scrape.indexOf(c[0])).sort();
  const split = indexes.map((index, j) => scrape.slice(index, indexes[j+1]));
  return split;
}
```

The sample above won't detect multiple occurrences of the same category in the scrape string, and it will only handle the first one (if a second parameter is not provided, [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) only detects the first occurrence). In order to detect multiple occurrences, I'd suggest replacing the function with this one:

```
function splitScrape(categories, scrape) {
  const indexes = [];
  categories.flat().filter(String).forEach(c => {
    let index = scrape.indexOf(c);
    while (index > -1) {
      indexes.push(index);
      index = scrape.indexOf(c, index + 1);
    }
  });
  indexes.sort((a, b) => a-b);
  const split = indexes.map((index, j) => scrape.slice(index, indexes[j+1])).filter(String);
  return split;
}
```

- Now, if you go back to your spreadsheet, you can use this function like any in-built one. You just have to provide the appropriate ranges where the `Categories` and the scrape string are located, as you can see here:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: Hi! This worked. Thank you.

Though when expanding it from 3 categories to 20/25 categories, some don't split. Is there something in the function that puts a limit on certain characters?

For instance

1. Maximale Breedte and 2. Product Breedte. The result of the scrape is "Maximale breedte97.1 cmProduct breedte97.50 cm". But it doesnt seem to split.

Comment: @Scraper2022 Can you provide a dataset to replicate this?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oQD58hgiNWyE5ZSYL81z0GKJX_QcbPJ6JzhKnZGGC5A/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Scraper2022 I think the problem is some categories (e.g. `Product Breedte`) are appearing multiple times in your script, and this function only handles the first one. I edited my answer and provided an alternative function to tackle this.